# How to perform 2D convolution on the gradient using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to perform 2D convolution between the Gaussian kernel and the gradient operator. Since the gradient is composed of both a vertical component and a horizontal component, my problem is how to choose the size of the Gaussian kernel. I have tried as follows,

```
[ux, uy]=grad(u);
```

```
G=fspecial('gaussian',[size(u,1) size(u,2)],1);
```

```
Convolution = [conv2(ux,G,'same'),conv2(uy,G,'same')];
```

Could you please help me to understand whether what I have tried is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper approach is to convolve the image `u` with the derivatives of the Gaussian kernel. These derivatives can be computed numerically (i.e. without using the finite difference approximation to the derivative as used in the `grad` function). For more information, see [this old blog post of mine](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/22). In short, instead of computing *G**(∇*f*), as OP's requirement, one can compute (∇*G*)**f*, which is exactly the same thing, but can be computed with a much smaller error in the discrete world. Here, * is the convolution operator, ∇ is the gradient operator, *G* is the Gaussian kernel, and *f* is the image. Note that ∇(*G***f*) is also the same thing! This is because all these operators commute.

The gradient is a vector with two components, and hence your gradient image will have two components. You can encode this as two separate images, one for the derivative in the x direction and one for the derivative in the y direction. This is the easiest solution in most image processing environments. The Gaussian gradient could be computed like so:

```matlab
img = single(imread('cameraman.tif'));
sigma = 1;
cutoff = ceil(3*sigma);
h = fspecial('gaussian',[1,2*cutoff+1],sigma);
dh = h .* (-cutoff:cutoff) / (-sigma^2);
dx = conv2(dh,h,img,'same');
dy = conv2(h,dh,img,'same');
```

---

If you want to handle gradients and similar in a nicer way, I suggest you use [DIPimage](https://diplib.github.io/DIPimage.html), a MATLAB toolbox that I designed. There, a gradient image is a single image where each pixel has two components (or three if it's a 3D image). It allows you to write further processing on that gradient image in a much more concise way than other libraries. A typical example is computing the [Harris corner detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harris_Corner_Detector):

```matlab
img = readim('trui');
g = gradient(img,1);
S = gaussf(g*g',5);
corners = det(S) - 0.04 * trace(S).^2;
```

The image `g` in this bit of code is the Gaussian gradient of the image `img`, i.e. both the `dx` and `dy` images we created earlier.

Comment: Many thanks for your very helpful answer.  I saw the useful link that you suggested and I understood that  ''computing the gradient of an image blurred with a Gaussian is the same thing as convolving the image with the gradient of a Gaussian'' but I need to convolve the gradient of image with a gaussian kernel as conv2(g,grad u) where u is the image, ang g is the gaussian kernel and grad u is the gradient of u. Can I perform this case similar to the procedure that you mentioned? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @eli Convolution and the gradient operator commute. That is, you get the same result no matter in what order you perform the two operations. `conv(g,grad(u))` is the same as `grad(conv(g,u))`, and also the same as `conv(grad(g),u)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and very useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider doing this in the frequency domain by taking the Fourier Transform of your image functions. https://www.dspguide.com/ch24/6.htm It is a lot quicker.

Comment: Yes, but I need to learn how to perform this code without using the Fourier transform. I am confused with this problem because the gradient is composed of both a horizontal and a vertical component and I do not know how to choose the guassian kernel in this case.